# Deactivate default ports of systemd socket activation

Tags: apache-2.4, systemd, socket, centos8

I have an Apache Server running on CentOS 8.2, whose sockets are managed by systemd socket activation. But I don't want it to listen on the default port 80, because I want to run a reverse proxy with Nginx at this port. Here's the current systemd socket configuration:

```
root@server6:~# systemctl status httpd.socket
● httpd.socket - Apache httpd Server Socket
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.socket; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/httpd.socket.d
           └─20-redir8016.conf, 30-listen8017ssl.conf, override.conf
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2020-11-20 14:45:13 UTC; 1 weeks 0 days ago
     Docs: man:httpd.socket(8)
   Listen: [::]:80 (Stream)
           [::]:8001 (Stream)
           [::]:8002 (Stream)
           [::]:8003 (Stream)
    Tasks: 0 (limit: 820374)
   Memory: 0B
   CGroup: /system.slice/httpd.socket
```

As you can see, port 80 is enabled. This is by default. The other ports were added deliebrately. The manpage of `httpd.socket(8)` only describes how to add another port, not how to remove the default ones. Port 80 is not configured in any configuration file in `/etc/httpd`.

How can I deactivate port 80 here? Where is the default configuration stored?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can list the files being used by systemd for the socket by using:

```
$ systemctl cat httpd.socket
```

and on my system this shows (some lines removed to keep it short):

```
# /usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.socket
[Unit]
Description=Apache httpd Server Socket
[Socket]
ListenStream=80
[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target

# /usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.socket.d/10-listen443.conf
[Socket]
ListenStream=443
```

You can see that 2 named files are used (on my system) to listen on ports 80 and 443. You can use `sudo systemctl edit httpd.socket` to add more configuration. To actually *cancel* an existing configuration, you need to use the standard systemd method of entering **an empty value** for the keyword, i.e. in this case: `ListenStream=`, followed by any wanted additional values:

```
[Socket]
# cancel existing port 80 (and 443)
ListenStream=
ListenStream=8001
ListenStream=8002
ListenStream=8003
```

---

`man systemd.syntax` (or `man systemd.unit` in older versions) says

> Various settings are allowed to be specified more than once, in which case
> the interpretation depends on the setting. Often, multiple settings form a
> list, and setting to an empty value "resets", which means that previous
> assignments are ignored.

Comment: Thanks, that was it! Really nicely explained. Even learned a helpful new command. I have now created a matching `00-resetports.conf` in the drop-in directory. Follow-up question: Where in the docs does it say that entering an empty value for a keyword cancels existing configuration? I couldn't find it.

Comment: I updated the answer: the info comes from `man systemd.unit` which includes `.service` `.socket` files, and many other types of unit.

Comment: Again, thanks for the addendum. On my system however, that info is at `systemd.syntax(7)`.